# How can I set up session storage with NestJS, Prisma and Postgres?

Tags: nestjs, prisma, session-storage

How can I set up session storage with NestJS, Prisma and Postgres? Are there any specific packages or configurations that need to be implemented? Can someone provide an example or guide on how to implement this using Postgres as the database?

Comment: What do you want to save in`SessionStorage`? I think your best bet is to use the `Session` guide from the NestJS website, NestJS is a pretty complete framework and supports all kinds of different things (for other things you might run into and wonder how it's done) https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/session

Comment: i want to use prisma orm to write session in postgres